# Rounding Decimals to whole numbers

Tags: c++

I was looking around and could not find exactly what I was looking for.

I want to round all my numbers up to the whole number.

Example: 
5.9 would be 6
5.5 would be 6
5.1 would be 6
5.000001122 would be 6
5.0 would be 5

I was thinking if I put them into ints that would get rid of the decimal but it did not look right as the decimals were just dropping off. Am I correct here?

So I thought about just doing that then adding 1 to the final result which would fix about 99% of the problem but if my result is 5 I do not want to add 1 to it.

How would I go about fixing this issue I have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for the `ceil()` function from `<math.h>` or `std::ceil()` from `<cmath>`.

Comment: If you're using c++ stick to <cmath> rather than <math.h> and use std::ceil(). The old C headers are considered deprecated [depr.c.headers].

Answer (score 8):

> [...] but it did not look right as the decimals were just dropping off. Am I correct here?

Correct, casting to an int simply discards the fractional part (i.e. rounds *toward zero*).

While `std::ceil()` from cmath will work for all the examples in your question, the question does not specify the required behaviour for *negative* values.  For example should -5.9 round to -6.0 or -5.0?  ceil(-5.9) = 5.0, which may not be what you want.  If you want -6.0, then you would need floor(-5.9), so the code would have to be:

```
round =  f > 0 ? std::ceil(f) : std::floor(f) ;
```

The question is whether you are rounding *up* as ceil() does, or rather rounding *away from zero* (up in magnitude rather than up in value) which the above code does?

Answer (score 0):

Use math.h function ceil(number)